# C: I can't get this example tax program to work

Tags: c

This program is supposed to take your income and taxes already paid, and determine what you owe or are owed. It doesnt work.

Some of the warnings it is giving me are the bracket variables being assigned values that are never used, and conditions always being true/false. I have no idea what I'm missing.

```
#include<stdio.h>

void main() {
    int income, paid;
    float tax, owed;
    float bracket1, bracket2, bracket3, bracket4, bracket5, bracket6;

    printf("Enter taxable income: ");
    scanf("%d", &income);
    printf("Enter tax paid during the year: ");
    scanf("%d", &paid);

    // Determines amount paid in each tax bracket
    bracket1 = (17,850 - 0) * 0.10;
    bracket2 = (72,500 - 17,851) * 0.15 - 893;
    bracket3 = (146,400 - 72,501) * 0.25 - 8143;
    bracket4 = (223,050 - 146,401) * 0.28 - 12,535;
    bracket5 = (398,350 - 223,051) * 0.33 - 23,688;
    bracket6 = (450,000 - 398,351) * 0.35 - 31,655;

    // Determines total tax owed
    if (income > 0 && income <= 17,850)
        tax = income * 0.10;
    else if (income > 17,850 && income <= 72,500)
        tax = bracket1 + (income - 17,850) * 0.15 - 893;
    else if (income > 72,500 && income <= 146,400)
        tax = bracket1 + bracket2 + (income - 72,500) * 0.25 - 8143;
    else if (income > 146,400 && income <= 223,050)
        tax = bracket1 + bracket2 + bracket3 + (income - 146,400) * 0.28 - 12,535;
    else if (income > 223,050 && income <= 398,350)
        tax = bracket1 + bracket2 + bracket3 + bracket4 + (income - 223,050) * 0.33 - 23,688;
    else if (income > 398,350 && income <= 450,000)
        tax = bracket1 + bracket2 + bracket3 + bracket4 + bracket5 + (income - 398,350) * 0.35 - 31,655;
    else if (income > 450,000)
        tax = bracket1 + bracket2 + bracket3 + bracket4 + bracket5 + bracket6 + (income - 450,000) * 0.396 - 52,355;
    else

    owed = tax - paid;

    if (owed > 0)
        printf("Tax due is %.02f", owed);   
    else if (owed < 0)
        printf("Refund is %.02f", owed); }
```

Right, so as for the errors Im getting.

```
Line 17: Code has no effect in function main
Line 18: Code has no effect in function main
Line 19: Code has no effect in function main
Line 22: Condition is always true in function main
Line 24: Condition is always true in function main
Line 26: Condition is always true in function main
Line 28: Condition is always true in function main
Line 29: Code has no effect in function main
Line 30: Condition is always true in function main
Line 31: Code has no effect in function main
Line 32: Condition is always false in function main
Line 33: Code has no effect in function main
Line 33: Unreachable code in function main
Line 34: Condition is always false in function main
Line 35: Unreachable code in function main
Line 35: Code has no effect in function main
Line 35: 'tax' is assigned a value that is never used in function main
Line 43: Function should return a value in function main
Line 14-19: 'bracket 1-6' is assigned a value that is never used in function main
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you post the errors that you are getting?

Comment: You're missing how to ask a good question. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. What you've asked is "I'm getting a bunch of errors but I'm not going to tell you what they are, now please help".

Comment: `main()` should return `int` not `void`.

Comment: and what happens if the amount owed is zero?

Comment: I added the specific errors.

Comment: One of your problems is that `450,000` (as one example) is not a number in C.  The compiler sees `450` followed by the comma operator followed by `000` and gets confused.  `450000`, on the other hand, is a number.  You need to fix all those numeric constants by removing the comma.

Comment: @indiv That helped a lot. I still have the errors on Lines 35 and 43 though.

Comment: @krabby , Change `void main()` to `int main(void)` and add a `return 0` before `}` of `main`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. Do not combine ints and floats in arifmetics it rounds result to int.
2. Use "." in digits "," is not for that.
3. One extra else does not allow to calculate owed.

Fixed:

```
#include<stdio.h>

void main() {
    float income, paid;
    float tax, owed;
    float bracket1, bracket2, bracket3, bracket4, bracket5, bracket6;

    printf("Enter taxable income: ");
    scanf("%f", &income);
    printf("Enter tax paid during the year: ");
    scanf("%f", &paid);

    // Determines amount paid in each tax bracket
    bracket1 = (17.850 - 0) * 0.10;
    bracket2 = (72.500 - 17.851) * 0.15 - 893;
    bracket3 = (146.400 - 72.501) * 0.25 - 8143;
    bracket4 = (223.050 - 146.401) * 0.28 - 12.535;
    bracket5 = (398.350 - 223.051) * 0.33 - 23.688;
    bracket6 = (450.000 - 398.351) * 0.35 - 31.655;

    // Determines total tax owed
    if (income > 0 && income <= 17.850)
        tax = income * 0.10;
    else if (income > 17.850 && income <= 72.500)
        tax = bracket1 + (income - 17.850) * 0.15 - 893;
    else if (income > 72.500 && income <= 146.400)
        tax = bracket1 + bracket2 + (income - 72.500) * 0.25 - 8143;
    else if (income > 146.400 && income <= 223.050)
        tax = bracket1 + bracket2 + bracket3 + (income - 146.400) * 0.28 - 12.535;
    else if (income > 223.050 && income <= 398.350)
        tax = bracket1 + bracket2 + bracket3 + bracket4 + (income - 223.050) * 0.33 - 23.688;
    else if (income > 398.350 && income <= 450.000)
        tax = bracket1 + bracket2 + bracket3 + bracket4 + bracket5 + (income - 398.350) * 0.35 - 31.655;
    else if (income > 450.000)
        tax = bracket1 + bracket2 + bracket3 + bracket4 + bracket5 + bracket6 + (income - 450.000) * 0.396 - 52.355;

    owed = tax - paid;

    if (owed > 0)
        printf("Tax due is %.02f", owed);
    else if (owed < 0)
        printf("Refund is %.02f", owed);
}
```

Also check bracket2 and 3, strange numbers, i dont belive in correct result